# Can I use different pronouns in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Q:Why do the monsters scare the children?
A:Because **they** can get electricity to light up **their** city from **their** screams.

Can I use different pronouns in a sentence?

Thank you:)

Comment: Your example creates confusion because of using the same pronoun to refer to monsters and to children.

Comment: 'Why do ogres eat horses? Because they like their taste.' And 'Why do good chefs consider it best to buy direct, not from supermarkets? Because they know their onions.' use 'their' in different ways (ref DO of 1st sentence; ref SUB of 1st sentence) but seem clear enough. But ambiguity/fuzziness soon creeps in.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your explanations! :)